# Delete link doesn't work, redirecting back to show Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a web application where users can create and manage their jogging sessions (jogs). Admin users should be able to delete any jog, while regular users should only be able to delete their own jogs. Additionally, managers should be able to delete their own jogs, but not jogs of other users. I've set up the appropriate conditions in the controller's destroy action to handle these permissions. However, despite implementing these conditions, I'm facing issues with the delete functionality:

As an admin, I can delete my own jogs, but I'm unable to delete jogs created by other users, the link is shown but when i click on it I get back to my root_url and nothing happens and I get no error.

```
class JogsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
    before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy
    before_action :set_jog, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authorize_jog_deletion, only: :destroy

    def weekly_report
      @jog = Jog.find(params[:id])
      @selected_week = params[:week].to_i if params[:week].present?
    end


    def create
    @jog = current_user.jogs.build(jog_params)
    if @jog.save
    flash[:success] = "Jog session created!"
    redirect_to root_url
    else
        @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
        render 'static_pages/home'        
    end
    end
  
    def destroy
      authorize_jog_deletion
      @jog.destroy
     flash[:success] = "Jog deleted"
     redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
    end

    

   
    
    private

    def jog_params
        params.require(:jog).permit(:distance_km, :duration_minutes, :date)
    end  

    def correct_user
        @jog = current_user.jogs.find_by(id: params[:id])
        redirect_to root_url if @jog.nil?
      end
      
      def set_jog
        @jog = Jog.find(params[:id])
      end

      def authorize_jog_deletion
        unless current_user.admin? ||
               (@jog.user == current_user) ||
               (current_user.manager? && current_user == @jog.user)
          flash[:danger] = "You are not authorized to delete this jog"
          redirect_to (root_url)
        end
      end
     
end
```

app/views/jogs/_jog.html.erb

```
<div class="weekly-report-button-container">
<%= link_to "View Weekly Report", weekly_report_jog_path(jog), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div class="weekly-report-button-container">
<li id="jog-<%= jog.id %>">

  <%= link_to gravatar_for(jog.user, size: 50), jog.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to jog.user.name, jog.user %></span>
  <span class="content">
    Distance: <%= jog.distance_km %> km |
    Duration: <%= jog.duration_minutes %> minutes |
    Date: <%= jog.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') %>
  </span>
  <span class="average-speed">Average Speed: <%= jog.average_speed %> km/h</span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Jogged on the site <%= time_ago_in_words(jog.date) %> ago.
    
    <% if current_user.admin? || (current_user.manager? && jog.user_id == current_user.id) || (jog.user_id == current_user.id) %>
    <%= button_to "delete", jog_path(jog), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this jog?" } %>
  <% end %>
  
  </span>
</li>

app/models/jog.rb
```

class Jog < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user

validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :date, presence: true , inclusion: { in: (Date.new(2020)..Date.today) }
validates :distance_km, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
validates :duration_minutes, presence: true

def admin?
admin
end

def manager?
manager
end

def self.calculate_weekly_total_distance(user)
weekly_total_distance = {}

```
user.jogs.each do |jog|
  week = jog.date.cweek
  weekly_total_distance[week] ||= 0
  weekly_total_distance[week] += jog.distance_km
end

weekly_total_distance
```

end

def average_speed
return 0 if duration_minutes.zero?

```
(distance_km / duration_hours).round(2)
```

end

private

def duration_hours
duration_minutes / 60.0
end
end

```
config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'static_pages#home'
    get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
    get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
    get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
    get 'signup' => 'users#new'
    get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
    post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
    delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resources :jogs, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :jogs do
    member do
      get :weekly_report
    end
  end
  
end
```

I've also tried switching the delete link to a button, and I've confirmed that the conditions are correctly set in the controller's destroy action. Despite all these efforts, I'm still facing these issues. Also, other delete links work in my app but this one doesn't.

Comment: `correct_user` runs before `authorize_jog_deletion`. also you have `authorize_jog_deletion`  before_action and you call it in destroy.

Comment: ok, so you suggest to change the order of the before actions, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`correct_user` sets `@jog` which is unexpected and also always uses `current_user` which is not what you want if current_user is admin:

```rb
class JogsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :set_jog, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :weekly_report]
  before_action :authorize_jog_deletion, only: :destroy
  # before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy

  def weekly_report
    # @jog = Jog.find(params[:id])
    @selected_week = params[:week].to_i if params[:week].present?
  end

  def create
    @jog = correct_user.jogs.new(jog_params)
    if @jog.save
      flash[:success] = "Jog session created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = correct_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      render "static_pages/home"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    # authorize_jog_deletion
    @jog.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Jog deleted"
    # redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
    redirect_back_or_to root_path
  end

  private

  # as admin you want to manage other people's stuff so you need to act on
  # their behalf
  # https://github.com/ankane/pretender
  def correct_user
    @correct_user ||= if current_user.admin?
      # figure out a way to set the user, it cannot be current_user, because
      # that's you, and you need the other guy
      @jog&.user || User.find(params[:user_id])
    else
      current_user
    end
  end

  # don't reinvent it
  # https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan
  # https://github.com/varvet/pundit
  def authorize_jog_deletion
    unless current_user.admin? || (@jog.user == current_user)
      # seems redundant. this covers it ^
      # || (current_user.manager? && current_user == @jog.user)

      flash[:danger] = "You are not authorized to delete this jog"
      redirect_to(root_url)
    end
  end

  def set_jog
    @jog = Jog.find(params[:id])
  end

  def jog_params
    params.require(:jog).permit(:distance_km, :duration_minutes, :date)
  end
end
```